# App Transport Security does not work any more with iOS 11 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, app-transport-security

I've been working on an app...since the iOS 11 update disabling ATS does not work anymore I've added the below in the info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

I can't use the domain exception key as I am downloading images from unknown domains.
below is what I get when trying to download an image

```
Task <C3DC30F1-5869-46F6-ABA4-5E1EC8334FD8>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1005 [4:-4])
NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1005
```

Comment: It might be that the error is not connected to ATS, but indicates an network timeout. Could you check this before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372318

Comment: ATS exception works with iOS11. There might be some other issue with your code or at server side.

Answer (score 4):

I am aware that IOS 11 not longer supports the following:

- RC4 3DES-CBC AES-CBC
- MD5 SHA-1
- <2048-bit RSA Pub Keys - All TLS connections to servers
- http://
- SSLv3
- TLS 1.0
- TLS 1.1

Adding the following we can bypass the ATS (App Transport Security) error:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key> <dict>
     <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
     <dict>
         <key>mydomain.com</key>
         <dict>
             <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
             <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
             <true/>
             <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
             <false/>
         </dict>
     </dict> </dict>
```

Reference link : [iOS 11 ATS (App Transport Security) no longer accepts custom anchor certs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316604/ios-11-ats-app-transport-security-no-longer-accepts-custom-anchor-certs)

Answer (score 0):

I had also faced same issue where I was getting following errors -

```
Task <DEBDD8DA-3D0D-43E0-B61A-CEFBDD6FF070>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
finished with error - code: -1001
Task <2C0D248B-1FBE-4DA0-B50A-0421E2509F42>.<2> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out.
```

Earlier I was using **Automatically manage signing** option under the General tab. When I have created new provisional profiles, I was not having this issue anymore.

**Solution -** Don't use **Automatically manage signing** option and create and add your **Provisional Profiles**.