# Should I add ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption to yes in plist in iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am using base 64 bit encryption for encrypting the string while sending request over the network in some web apis.

Please let me know in iTunes connect, should I select yes for encryption?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

As far as you are sending encrypted content over network using iOS's encoding technique base64 encoding, you need to mark it as **NO**.

You are not using any encryption techniques like AES, DES, RSA, so you are not using encryption at all.

Base64 is not encryption - It is an encoding technique.

> **Question** : Is your app designed to use cryptography or does it contain or incorporate cryptography?
>
> **Answer** : "**YES**" to the question if your app is using encryption. Some
>   examples of encryption use include:
>
> - Making calls over secure channels (i.e. HTTPS, SSL, and so on)
> - Using standard encryption algorithms
> - Using crypto functionality from other sources such as iOS or macOS
> - Using proprietary or non-standard encryption algorithms
>
> Answer “**NO**” if your app does not use, access, implement or incorporate
>   encryption.
>
> **Question** : Does your app implement any standard encryption algorithms instead of, or in addition to, using or accessing the
>   encryption in Apple’s iOS or macOS?
>
> **Answer** : "**YES**" to the question if your app implements industry standard algorithms such as AES, DES, RSA, and so on, instead of or in
>   addition to accessing or using the encryption algorithms available in
>   Apple’s iOS or macOS.
>
> Answer “**NO**” if your app does not implement industry standard
>   algorithms instead of, or in addition to, accessing or using the
>   encryption algorithms available in Apple’s iOS or macOS.

For more information visit [Q&A for iTunes Connect](https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Managing%20Your%20Apps_Export%20Compliance#56254694).

**Update for Comment about ATS :**

```
NSAllowsArbitraryLoads
```

Since release of iOS 10 and later, and macOS 10.12 and later, by setting this key as Boolean value YES, disables App Transport Security (ATS). Which may result in [rejection of Application from App Store Review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47300932/app-transport-security-does-not-work-any-more-with-ios-11-xcode-9).

> **Use of this key triggers App Store review and requires justification.**

So it is recommended to use HTTPS server with `TLSv1.2` support.

Enabling this key can also be useful for debugging and development.

> NOTE: Disabling ATS allows connection regardless of HTTP or HTTPS
>   configuration, allows connection to servers with lower Transport Layer
>   Security (TLS) versions, and allows connection using cipher suites
>   that do not support perfect forward secrecy (PFS).
>
> This key’s default value of NO results in default ATS behavior for all
>   connections except those for which you have specified an exception
>   domain dictionary.

Comment: Thanks @technerd, Please let me know one thing also, we are accessing web on the http also and it is working without the transport security entry in the plist, but I have already added the security check arbitrary load to yes, is this ok?

Comment: @GopalDevra : Answer updated for use of ATS in Application.