# Swift: HTTP load failed (error code: 100)

Tags: json, swift, url

When i run this code it will give me this error:

> 2018-05-03 18:06:05.605035+0200 FNStats[4225:1826491] Task
>   .<1> HTTP load failed (error
>   code: 100 [1:100]) 2018-05-03 18:06:05.605179+0200
>   FNStats[4225:1826493] Task .<1>
>   finished with error - code: 100

Can someone explaine to me what I am doing wrong!

```
let urlString = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/Danikemper010"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
request.setValue("TRN-Api-Key: c400d2a8-8a99-45e7-a62b-3cef2d74ce14", forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key: c400d2a8-8a99-45e7-a62b-3cef2d74ce14")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    if let responseData = data
    {
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            print(json)
        }catch{
            print("Could not serialize")
        }
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: Are you setting the HTTPHeaderField correctly? Looks like the same string is both value and key.

Comment: I am not sure. The documentation says: To make use of our APIs we require you to use an API Key. To use the API key you need to pass it along as a header with your requests.

TRN-Api-Key: c400d2a8-8a99-45e7-a62b-3cef2d74ce14 . 
 https://fortnitetracker.com/site-api

Comment: this solution worked for me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868844/5032981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. The header field is "TRN-Api-Key" and the value for that field is your key.

```
let urlString = "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/profile/pc/Danikemper010"
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
request.setValue("c400d2a8-8a99-45e7-a62b-3cef2d74ce14", forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

     if let responseData = data {

        print("We have some data")

        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
            print(json)
        }catch{
            print("Could not serialize")
        }
    }            
}
task.resume()
```