# AFNetwork: Getting "finished with error - code: -999" warning

Tags: ios, api, afnetworking, httpresponse

I am doing a `get` API request and everything works fine, but I am getting the following warning in the console.

> Task <13369ECB-128E-41B7-B9E4-DC7D3E47D0C1>.<2> finished with error -
>   code: -999

This only occurs for a certain API endpoint. This makes no sense to me at all. I thought -999 stands for cancelled request, but my requests are finished.

I think this might be a security issue simply because all my `get` requests work for multiple api endpoints, but not a specific one. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52868844/5032981. It worked in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this means it was canceled, but the question is why

1. be patient to make sure you didn't cancel the request.
2. returned when an asynchronous load is canceled. A **Web Kit framework** delegate will receive this error when it performs a cancel operation on a loading resource.
3. may be caused by an invalid SSL certificate